# Bigtable cluster throughout vs client throughput

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

I have noticed that when I run tests against google cloud Bigtable the throughout graphs on the client machine show drastically different numbers from those on the Bigtable graphs. For example, right now I am running test and I see Bigtable read bandwidth graph showing about 25MB-30MB/sec and the GCE client machine which runs in the same zone shows network bytes as 5K/sec. There is only one client running against Bigtable and this is a fairly modest sequential stream of reads and writes hitting Bigtable. I am wondering why is there such a drastic difference in numbers and if this is the expected behavior how does that high read bandwidth that Bigtable graphs show affects overall cluster performance? My concern is that the cluster resources might get drained very quickly by just a few clients each of which doing very little. Write bandwidth was at zero when that test run.

Comment: Sorry to hear about the issue. This question needs more information for us to investigate it further which I would not advise posting publicly. If you have GCP Support plan, please open a ticket and include: project id, cluster id, zone, client library language and version. If not, please [contact us](https://cloud.google.com/contact/) with the same info so that we can investigate. Please also mention my name in the message, I am the product manager for Bigtable. Thanks!